# Image search by sketching, who has implemented?

Tags: image, service, drawing, pattern-matching

Online mentions of algorithms for finding image data based on sketching exist, e.g. here: http://garmahis.com/software/search-photos-by-sketch-or-image-with-retrievr-and-imgseek/

I want to write a webapplication that uses such an algorithm, where the algorithm has been implemented and made into a service by someone else. I'm surprised that Google hasn't implemented on their own API.

Anyone know of an online service that does this, and is ready to be used? The data set that is searched could be whatever this service has indexed (like Google image index) or maybe a set of user supplied images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TinyEye](http://www.tineye.com/) can find pages containing a given image (consider it to be a reverse image search), but it has to be exactly the same.
Otherwise, there is [GaZoPa](http://www.gazopa.com/), which searches based primarily off composition.
And there is [Idee Labs BYO Search](http://labs.ideeinc.com/), which is similar to GaZoPa, but searches primarily based off colour.

Comment: Tineye even finds altered images (not just cropped): http://www.tineye.com/search/94016dc34e74d09d12cc472a9f3c7f48a2308f4e/

Comment: Actually GazoPa could be turned into a sketch and query service. I made a crude sketch of a dog in Dia, uploaded it, and it found a picture of a dog as the [first hit](http://skipperkongen.dk/2011/04/01/image-search-by-sketching-continued/). So not bad, thanks.

Comment: I love our futuristic present.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for something simple to integrate with an existing system, I have written a Perl module which is built on the exact same underlying mathematics as imgSeek and isk-daemon.

It is called WMatch, and it is much simpler.  It provides just the image comparison functions. It allows you to use your own database for storing the image signatures.

You can download it from www.spiderfan.org/pkg/wmatch.tar.gz

It gives the same results as imgSeek, but is simpler and standalone, idea for server scripting if you want to integrate with an existing system.

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer.WMatch really works good for my image data. I have no knowledge of perl and wanted to know how I could give my images to WMatch and make the code work for my image dataset?

Comment: Ah, you'll have to learn some Perl first.  Then...

use WMatch::Process;

my $magick = new Image::Magick->new();
$magick->BlobToImage ($image_bin_content);
my $sig = &signature ($magick);

Comment: @the.jxc: Is there some demonstration of what you are actually doing and how you are doing, i dont know perl, i will for sure spend some time on perl syntax. But a small demo can be really helpful

Comment: The client page using this feature is http://www.spiderfan.org/comics/ which just uses a standard file uploader to push a file to the server.

Comment: I really need to put this in a proper document, don't I!  The client side is just any file uploader you like.  www.spiderfan.org/comics/ is a simple client-side example.  On the server side... contact me via www.spiderfan.org and I'll email you the find_cover.pl from the server side.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [isk-daemon](http://server.imgseek.net/):

> isk-daemon is an open source database server capable of adding content-based (visual) image searching to any image related website or software.
>
> This technology allows users of any image-related website or software to sketch on a widget which image they want to find and have the website reply to them the most similar images or simply request for more similar photos at each image detail page.

Comment: +1 This is very interesting. I can think of several applications, since many types of data can be represented as images.